# How to center an unnumbered section name?

Tags: sectioning

I have a chapter `chap1.tex` in latex project `project.tex` which has the following sections:

```
\chapter{Overview}
    \section*{Introduction}
    \section{Model}
    \section{Discussion}
```

When I run my latex project `project.tex`, I will get something like this:
[image]

I would like to make `Introduction` in the center. How to do this?

I tried `\centering\section*{Introduction}`

Comment: Do you only want unnumbered sections centred?

Comment: Yes. For example the introduction section.

Comment: A comment up front: It may look very weird if unnumbered section headers are centered but numbered sections are not. To center-set both numbered and unnumbered section headers, you could load the `sectsty` package and issue the directive `\sectionfont{\centering}`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you are using a `\section*` for it, there are no complications for the table of contents.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Overview}
    \section*{\hfil Introduction\hfil}
    \section{Model}
    \section{Discussion}
\noindent\hrulefill
\end{document}
```

[image]

To address both a possible criticism of non-generality as well as the suggestion of egreg, one could implement the above idea as shown below:

```
\documentclass{book}
%\def\myformat#1{\hfil #1\hfil}% OR ALTERNATELY
\def\myformat#1{\centering#1}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Overview}
    \section*{\myformat{Introduction}}
    \section{Model}
    \section{Discussion}
\noindent\hrulefill
\end{document}
```

In this way, a desire at some future point to change the format for all such starred sections would require only a single-line change to the document, that is, the definition of `\myformat`.

Comment: Probably `\section*{\centering Introduction}` is better.

Comment: my apologies again - please see my updated answer :)

Comment: Is there a reason this doesn't work in article?  I got an error about undefined control sequence \equal{Section}{Document}.

Comment: @AThomack For one, `article` class has no `\chapter` macro.  Though, I associate the `\equal` macro with the `ifthen` package, though maybe there are others, as well.

Answer (score 9):

One of the most useful aspects of using `LaTeX` and friends is that you can separate content from form; if you specify `\hfil...\hfil` for every unnumbered section, what happens if you change your mind later on?

As an alternative, you can use (for example) the [`titlesec`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/titlesec) package; the `\titleformat` command has syntax:

```
% from the titlesec package
%\titleformat{ command }
%             [ shape ]
%             { format }{ label }{ sep }{ before-code }[ after-code ]
```

Here's the complete code to play with:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
% from the titlesec package
%\titleformat{ command }
%             [ shape ]
%             { format }{ label }{ sep }{ before-code }[ after-code ]
% \section*
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
{\filcenter\Large\bfseries}
{}
{.5em}
{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Overview}
    \section*{Introduction}
    \section{Model}
    \section{Discussion}
\noindent\hrulefill
\end{document}
```

Comment: Obviously, one could `\def\myformat#1{\hfil #1\hfil}` and invoke `\section*{\myformat{Introduction}}`.  So I think your discouragement against use should be taken in the context of a likely implementation.  A later change of mind would require only a single line edit.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes you're absolutely right - I certainly didn't mean it to sound as harsh as it did, and will re-write that sentence; my apologies :)

Comment: Likewise, I'm sorry for my hyperventilation.